# Hospital's rule and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x \ln(x)}{1-x}$

Tags: calculus

We know that: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x \ln(x)}{1-x}$ = $\frac{0}{1}$ = 0

If we apply Hospital's rule we get:
$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x \ln(x)}{1-x}$ = $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(x)+1}{1}$ = $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} {\ln(x)+1}$ = -∞

Can you please tell me what am I missing. Thanks!

Comment: L'Hopital's rule doesn't apply unless the limit is of type $\frac 00$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: What is the hypothesis for l'Hopital again?

Comment: It applies only if the limit is in one of the many indeterminate forms, such as the ones said by @Bye_World

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply L'Hospital's rule only and only if the form of limit is 0/0 or ∞/∞ . In this case , it is clearly a finite value . Hence , the rule would not be applicable here .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the identity $$x\ln(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

and then apply l'Hopital.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @user251257: I think it does. If wants to calculate the limit by using the rule properly.